# how can you sort this folders contents alphabeticaly

Tags: php

I wonder can anyone help me, I use this script as part of tinymce, and this displays the names of the graphics in the pics folder, but I want to show them alphabeticaly. Is this possible ?

Thanks in advance
Eric

Script :

```
<?
echo 'var tinyMCEImageList = new Array(
';
$directory = "../pics";
if(is_dir($directory)){
$direc = opendir($directory);
$trenn = "";
while(false !== ($file = readdir($direc))){
    if($file !="." && $file != ".." ){
        if(is_file($directory."/".$file)){
            echo $trenn;
            $trenn = ",nt";
        echo '["'.$file.'", "../pics/'.$file.'"]';
        }
    }
}
closedir($direc);
}
echo ');'; 
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried searching StackOverflow and Google (etc) for things like "php alphabetical order", and "php order folders alphabetically"? I'm sure it must be such an easy solution, it will be just as easy to find ;)

Comment: Hi James, yeah I have tried googling etc but to no avail, I dont know if it is to be doen in javascript or php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**`glob`**](https://www.php.net/glob), then [**`natsort`**](https://www.php.net/natsort).

```
$arrFiles = glob("*"); //Fetch all files.
natsort( array_values($arrFiles) ); //Sort them using natural sort.
echo "<pre>";
echo print_r($arrFiles, true);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: thanks @hd, that is a great help !